# Initialize TPM virtual smart card in Google Cloud VM running Windows Server

Tags: google-compute-engine, rdp, tpm

After setting up a Windows Server with a vTPM (see https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/security-in-plaintext-use-shielded-vms-to-harden-your-gcp-workloads) in Google Cloud VM and accesing to it through Remote Desktop Services (RDS), when trying to initialize the TPM virtual smart card with a command like the following:

```
Tpmvscmgr.exe create /name "TestVirtualSC" /pin prompt /adminkey default /generate
```

The following error is produced:

```
Creating TPM Smart Card...
TPM Virtual Smart Card management cannot be used within a Terminal Services session.
    (0x800704d3) The request was aborted.
```

So, is there any way to initialize the TPM virtual smart card through a remote RDS session?, or alternatively, is there any other way to initialize it in a Google Cloud VM running Windows Server?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Emergency Management Services (EMS) console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc736319(v=ws.10)) which once connected, will present you with a Command Prompt.

1. From your terminal or in Cloud Shell, enable connections to the serial ports on your VM:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata <VM-NAME> --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
```

Replacing `<VM-NAME>` with the name of the VM on which to enable the serial ports.

2. Connect to the EMS console on serial port `2` of your VM:

```
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port <VM-NAME> --port 2
```

Replacing `<VM-NAME>` with the name of the VM with the serial port to connect to.

3. Verify that you see output similar to the following:

```
Computer is booting, SAC started and initialized.

Use the "ch -?" command for information about using channels.
Use the "?" command for general help.

SAC>
EVENT: The CMD command is now available.
SAC>
```

4. Create a new command prompt session by using the `cmd` command and verify output similar to the following:

```
The Command Prompt session was successfully launched.
SAC>
EVENT:   A new channel has been created.  Use "ch -?" for channel help.
Channel: Cmd0001
SAC>
```

5. Connect to the new command prompt session by using the `ch -si 1` command and verify output similar to the following:

```
Name:                  Cmd0001
Description:           Command
Type:                  VT-UTF8
Channel GUID:          28de7392-5413-11ea-bb03-c9656a2ed613
Application Type GUID: 63d02271-8aa4-11d5-bccf-00b0d014a2d0

Press <esc><tab> for next channel.
Press <esc><tab>0 to return to the SAC channel.
Use any other key to view this channel.
```

6. Press `Enter` to connect to the session.
7. Sign in to the session by entering your login credentials for this VM, after which the EMS console opens in the `C:\Windows\system32` directory. Type `help` for a list of available commands in the EMS console.

Links:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#ems-console
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc736319(v=ws.10) (Note: It says it applies to WS 2003, however it applies to all versions of Windows since 2003.